# How do i change an array based on another text field?

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a TheList.as class..in which i have created a list for an android app.
Here is TheList.as(Cut down to the specific stuff for this question)

```
public var _ListItem:ListItem;
public var _Data:Array;
public var _Values:Array; 
public var $CurrentValue:String;
public var _TextLabel:TextField;

public function TheList(Data:Array,Values:Array)
    {
        _Data = Data;
        _Values = Values;



        initialize();
    }

    private function initialize():void
    {

        _TextLabel = new TextField();
        addChild(_TextLabel);
        _TextLabel.text = "Data";
        _Container = new ListContainer  ;
        addChild(_Container);
        _Container.x = 0;
        _Container.y = 0;
        currentY = _Container.y;
        lastY = _Container.y;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < _Data.length; i++)
        {
            _ListItem = new ListItem  ;
            _Container.addChild(_ListItem);

            _ListItem.y = _ListItem.height * i;
                              _ListItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onItemDown,false,0,true);
            _ListItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onItemUp,false,0,true);
            _ListItem.mouseChildren = false;
            _ListItem.value = _Values[i];
            _ListItem.name = _Data[i];
            _ListItem.ItemLabel.text = _ListItem.name ;


        }

    }
```

Here is the class "TheList" is being used in (Again Cut Down to specific stuff)

```
$myList = new TheList($Data,$Values);
        addChild($myList);
        $myList.x = -240;
        $myList.y = -203;
        $myList.visible = false;

        $ListFrom = new TheList($DataFromTo, $ValuesFromTo);
        addChild($ListFrom);
        $ListFrom.x = -240;
        $ListFrom.y = -203;
        $ListFrom.visible = false;
        $ListFrom._TextLabel.text = $DataFromTo[0];

        $ListTo = new TheList($DataFromTo, $ValuesFromTo);
        addChild($ListTo);
        $ListTo.x = -240;
        $ListTo.y = -203;
        $ListTo.visible = false;
        $ListTo._TextLabel.text = $DataFromTo[0];
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is that i want to change "$Data" and "$Values" Arrays..as you can see i have a main list and two sublists... when "Time" is selected in the main list, i want the sub-lists to be populated with "Time" related unit names...i tried

```
if($myList._TextLabel.text == "Time")
{
 $ListFrom._Data = ["this", "this", "this" etc]
}
```

But its not working. I am not getting any error either. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Off Topic. Please look into the AS3 conventions for class, variable and field names. It hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to achieve is not pissible in this way. You initialize you lists with data fields. When you reset the data, you need to invalidate your list again. You can achieve this with an item setter

```
private var __Data:Array;

public function get _Data():Array
{
     return __Data;
}

public function set _Data(value:Array):void
{
     this.__Data = value;
     initialize();
}
```

make sure that you first cleanup you list before you rebuild it again.

your code:

```
$ListFrom._Data = ["this", "this", "this" etc]
```

will automaticly call the setter. A getter and setter method looks like a function but is invoked like a property. means:

```
object.property = "something" //will call the setter
var something:String = object.property //will call the getter
```

Comment: Right idea, note the initialize method as coded above would add new instances of the components in the list and the original ones would still be present. So you'd want to loop over the children of the list and remove them before the new items are created.

Comment: How do i set the value of the array? I mean i am using conditional in a different class..How do i say(if(myText.text == "something"){how do i use the set function here?})...."I have never used setters and getters before!"

Comment: You wrote the code already. The only thing you have to do is remove all list items from stage (like Sunil D. described) and call your initialize function again.

Comment: i tried but its still not working..when i trace the array, i can see that the values change...but they are not getting assigned to the list.